# Increment number in a div on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this solution with `<form>` and `<input>` elements.

```js
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" id="number" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
</form>
```

But how do I achieve same effect by clicking an `<a></a>` button and incrementing value inside a `<div></div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```js
const a = document.getElementById("a"),
  div = document.getElementById("div");
  
a.addEventListener("click", event => {
  //this is just to prevent redirects when you click the link
  event.preventDefault();
  
  //gets the number in div
  const num = parseInt(div.innerHTML);
  
  //increments the number
  div.innerHTML = num + 1;
});
```

```html
<a id="a" href="">Anchor Tag</a>
<div id="div">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a `button` rather than `anchor` which makes more sense as a html tag for that. You would manipulate property `innerText` for this:

```js
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').innerText, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').innerText = value;
}
```

```html
<div id="number"/>0</div>
<button onclick="incrementValue()" />Increment Value</button>
```